# Beautiful soup complicated query question

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to **scrape** the table on the following website

https://www.hkab.org.hk/DisplayInterestSettlementRatesAction.do

However, it has a very complicated query
[image]

I tried the following code but I cant find the table I want.

```
url = "https://www.hkab.org.hk/DisplayInterestSettlementRatesAction.do"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table',{'class':'etxtmed'})
```

And the table result is:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" class="etxtmed" width="100%">
<tr>
<td height="30" valign="top"><a href="index.jsp">Home</a>
</td>
<td align="right" class="etxtsml" valign="top">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can I get the value of the table? I cant find the table value.
Some comment say that it is generated by javascript, any suggestion for getting the table value instead of beautifulsoup?

Comment: There are five tables with class etxtmed on that page. You're only checking the first. Correction, it would seem the other tables are generated by javascript.

Comment: even if i use soup.findAll, it still give me the first table. How can i get all the table in this case?

Comment: You're going to need something that executes javascript such as Selenium. Search here in SO for tons of Selenium stuff.

Comment: ok.. i will try it out. One more question, for this website: https://www.global-rates.com/interest-rates/libor/libor.aspx, The link shows EUR libor but I want to get the USD libor. There is a button but when i use beautifulsoup with the input link, only EUR data can be obtained. Any idea on this ?

Comment: you can use selenium to push the USD button and then grab the page's HTML again from the same session. [Here's](https://pythonspot.com/selenium-click-button/) the docs for that

Comment: @KevinKwong Check my answer below !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tracked from where the data loaded and found the `url` to load from it :).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

r = requests.get(
    'https://www.hkab.org.hk/hibor/listRates.do?lang=en&Submit=Detail')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

mat = []
hk = []
for item in soup.findAll('td', {'align': 'right'})[2:]:
    item = item.text.strip()
    mat.append(item)
for item in soup.findAll('td', {'align': 'middle'})[3:11]:
    item = item.text
    hk.append(item)

data = []
for item in zip(mat, hk):
    data.append(item)

with open('output.csv', 'w+', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['Maturity', 'HKD Interest\nSettlement Rate'])
    writer.writerows(data)
    print("Operation Completed")
```

Output: [Click Here](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/476d9069d2318297b7442406faded372/output.csv)

[image]